# Updating geometry in SpriteKit (or SceneKit)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit, metal

We are porting a game to SpriteKit and I've run in to a bit of a problem. Some objects in our game have triangle-strip trails attached to them. The vertex buffers of the trails are continuously updated as the objects move in the world to create a seamless and flowing effect (there are constraints on how many vertices are in the buffer and how often we emit new vertices).

In the previous implementation we simply updated the affected vertices in the corresponding buffer whenever we emitted new vertices. In SceneKit it seems I am unable to update geometry sources, unless I use `geometrySourceWithBuffer:vertexFormat:semantic:vertexCount:dataOffset:dataStride:`. To do this however, it seems I need a Metal device, command queue and encoder, to be able to submit commands to update my buffer before it renders.

Is there any way I can do this with a normal `SCNView`, or do I have to do everything manually with a `CAMetalLayer`, creating my own metal device etc?

In essence, *everything* we need, bar this trail geometry is available in SpriteKit, so I was hoping there was some way I could get a hold of the metal device and command queue used by the SKView and simply use that to upload my geometry. This would make things *a lot* simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a particle system to get a similar effect. The particle emitter is attached to the moving object, with particles set to fade out and eventually die. You might need to set the emitter's `targetNode` to your scene, depending on the effect you want.

```
    emitter = SKEmitterNode()
    emitter.name = marbleNodeNames.trail.rawValue
    emitter.particleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "spark")
    emitter.particleAlphaSpeed = -1.0
    emitter.particleLifetime = 2
    emitter.particleScale = 0.2
    marbleSprite.addChild(emitter)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option as the strip is textured to give a continuous  swooping look. We use particle effects for other things, but this particular effect needs geometry to look and behave correctly. As a refrence please see http://imgur.com/QJvxM2H (not my image).

Comment: Can you add individual triangles as SCNShape instances, with an extrusion depth of 0? Perhaps subclass SCNNode to add an expiration time, if you need to remove the trail triangles periodically. Your could use the SCNRendererDelegate calls to trigger the search.

Comment: I think the way we'll solve it for now is using a SceneKit Scene as base, using the SpriteKit overlay scene to run the actual game. That way we can get the metal device from the SCNView. I'll try and do an answer once I have it all running. Thanks for the suggestions though!